# Can I know if radio button is unselected in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, radio-button

I have an array tagNames = {{value: Dog}, {value: Cat} ...} this array is created by user input.

```
 <div *ngFor = "let tag of tagNames">
          <input
              type = "radio"
              [value]= "tag.value"
              name = "tagName"
              (change) = "onclick($event)"> {{tag.value}}
  </div>

onclick(event) {
    for (let tag of this.tagNames) {
      this.temp[tag.value] = false;
    }
    let key = event.target.value;
    this.temp[key] = true;
  }
```

Is there a way for me to not have a loop in the onclick by having an event fire which lets me know the user selected the radio button associated with cat and therefore unselected Dog?

Comment: I recommend you to use hashmap

Comment: I was using a hashMap but JSON was seeing my hashMap as empty :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a few arrays running around, it might be a good idea to keep them in one array as an object. Could you use the `index` property for the ngfor and store it as a prev index? Also update your tagNames to look like this `tagNames = [{value: 'Dog', selected: false}, {value: 'Cat', slected: false}, ...]`

```
<div *ngFor = "let tag of tagNames; let i = index">
          <input
              type = "radio"
              [value]= "tag.selected"
              name = "tag.name"
              (change) = "onclick($event, i)"> {{tag.value}}
  </div>

prevIndex = 0;
onclick(event, index) {
    this.tagNames[this.prevIndex].selected = false;
    this.tagNames[index].selected = true;
    this.prevIndex = index;
  }
```

edit: This might be a good reference to look at https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_form_radio